# Matrizes em JAVA

Tags: java

Desejo fazer um boletim escolar em JAVA,uma matriz com 4 linhas que serão o número de alunos,e 4 colunas que serão as 4 notas de cada aluno
Usei um vetor para pegar a média no final,meu único problema é que eu desejo que primeiro todos os alunos coloquem suas notas para somente no fim imprimir na tela a média de cada um.
Não sei qual o problema com meu código,mas depois do 1º aluno colocar seu nome e suas notas,a partir do 2º ele já nao pede o nome,já vem direto para as notas e com o nome de "Null".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int TOTAL_ALUNOS = 4;
    final int TOTAL_BIMESTRES = 4;
    final double NOTA_MINIMA = 70.0;

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] nomeAlunos = new String[TOTAL_ALUNOS];
    double[][] notaAlunos = new double[TOTAL_ALUNOS][TOTAL_BIMESTRES];
    double[] mediaAlunos = new double[TOTAL_ALUNOS];

    //Obter nome dos alunos
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_ALUNOS; ++i) {
        System.out.println("Informe o nome do " + (i + 1) + "° aluno:");
        nomeAlunos[i] = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("");

        //Obter notas dos alunos todos os bimetres
        for (int y = 0; y < TOTAL_ALUNOS; ++y) {
            for (int j = 0; j < TOTAL_BIMESTRES; ++j) {
                System.out.println("Informe a nota do aluno " + nomeAlunos[y]
                        + " para o " + (j + 1) + "° bimestre");
                notaAlunos[y][j] = input.nextDouble();
            }
        }
    }

    //calcular media alunos
    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_ALUNOS; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < TOTAL_BIMESTRES; ++j) {
            mediaAlunos[i] += notaAlunos[i][j];
        }
        mediaAlunos[i] /= TOTAL_BIMESTRES;
    }

    //Mostrar situacao dos alunos
    System.out.println("======== RESULTADO FINAL =======");

    for (int i = 0; i < TOTAL_ALUNOS; ++i) {

        if (mediaAlunos[i] >= NOTA_MINIMA) {
            System.out.println("Nome: " + nomeAlunos[i] + " Media: " + mediaAlunos[i]
                    + " Situação: Aprovado");
            continue;
        }

        System.out.println("Nome: " + nomeAlunos[i] + " Media: " + mediaAlunos[i]
                + " Situação: Reprovado");
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 3):

Na leitura consecutiva de valores numéricos e String deve-se esvaziar o buffer do teclado antes da leitura do valor String, por exemplo:

```java
int n;
String s;

System.out.printf("Informe um Número Inteiro: ");
n = ler.nextInt();

ler.nextLine(); // esvazia o buffer do teclado

System.out.printf("Informe uma cadeia de caracteres:\n");
s = ler.nextLine();
```

Comment: Funcionou,muito obrigado Natan!

Comment: Só nao entendi uma coisa,funcionou muito bem agora,mas eu só  esvaziei após input do "nome",não usei após o usuário colocar as notas,mas não tá acumulando valor em cima do outro,poderia me explicar?pois vc disse que na leitura consecutiva de valores numéricos deve esvaziar.

Comment: porque ao utilizar o ler.nextLine(); na próxima interação do for ele limpara também os de valores numéricos. Fico feliz em ajudar.